# SubString gives OutOfMemory Exception when tried to give a very long string

Tags: java, string, substring

I am Working on this piece of code for a coding challenge from leet code.

This piece of code works for 986 test cases out of 987. It fails for a case of a very long string (length ~ 31600).
the substring function throws java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space.

I have tried creating the 'substring' new SubString(s.substring(i,j));
and s.substring(i,j).intern(); after seeing suggestions from other stack over flow. but in vain

```
private static Map<String, Integer> findAllSubStrings(String s) {
        Map<String, Integer> allSubStrings = new HashMap<>();
        for(int i = 0; i<s.length(); i++) {
            for(int j=i+1; j<=s.length(); j++) {
                String substring = s.substring(i,j);
                allSubStrings.put(substring, substring.length());
            }
        }
        return allSubStrings;
    }
```

The exception is,

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
at java.base/java.util.Arrays.copyOfRange(Arrays.java:4031)
at java.base/java.lang.StringLatin1.newString(StringLatin1.java:782)
at java.base/java.lang.String.substring(String.java:1888)
at main.LongestSubstring.findAllSubStrings(LongestSubstring.java:76)
at main.LongestSubstring.getLengthOfLongestSubString(LongestSubstring.java:44)
at main.LongestSubstring.main(LongestSubstring.java:38)
```

I am looking for anyone who can help me understand and fixing this issue.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does the challenge explicitly require you to return `Map<String, Integer>`?

Comment: No. I used the map to store the sub strings. That doesn’t definitely work for such a large string.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As the exception says, you're running out of space.

For a string of length `n`, there are `n(n-1)/2` different substrings to create; when n is around 32,000 this works out to about 500 *million* substrings. Each of the `String` objects takes up at least sixteen bytes of heap (but probably more than that, and that is even assuming they all share the same underlying `char[]`, such that we don't need to count the *contents* separately), so you'd need at least 8 GB to represent them all. Probably your default Java heap limit is not that large.

You'll need to go back to the drawing board and come up with an algorithm that doesn't depend on all the substrings being present in memory at the same time.

Comment: *... and that is even assuming they all share the same underlying char[]* - For a recent JVM, they don't.

Comment: @StephenC thanks for the detailed explanation. I will try and modify my algorithm more efficiently.

Comment: (The change which stopped `substring` from sharing the backing array was implemented in Java 8.  The `substring` method *now* creates a new `char[]` except in the degenerate case where it can return `this`.)

Comment: @StephenC: Indeed, but that just makes it worse for the OP.

Answer (score 0):

`substring()` returns a new string which cost some memory, storing all sub-strings will eventually consume all heap. You need to `consume` these sub strings right after it created (say,  comparing length to the longest length) instead of storing them in a collection.

Comment: I have tried this solution after reading your comment. It helped me get rid of my memory exception. But, I landed in time limit exceeded exception. I think I have to redesign my code as suggested by @Henning Makholm.